# Adding a join condition in the from clause *and* where clause makes query faster. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-tuning

I'm tuning a query for a large transactional financial system. I've noticed that including a join condition in the where clause *as well as* the from clause makes the query run significantly faster than either of the two individually. I note that the join in the from clause has more than one condition; I mention this in case it is significant. Here's a simplified example:

```
SELECT  *
FROM       employee e
INNER JOIN car c ON c.id = e.car_id AND -- some other join
-- Adding the join above again, in the where clause makes the query faster
WHERE c.id = e.car_id;
```

I thought ANSI vs old-school was purely syntactic. What's going on?

**Update**

Having analysed the two execution plans, it's clear that adding the same join in the where clause as the from clause, produces a very different execution plan than having the join in either of the two.

Comparing the plans, I could see what the plan with the additional where clause condition was doing better, and wondered why the one without, was joining in the way that it was. Knowing the optimal plan, a quick tweak to the join conditions resolved matters, although I'm still surprised that both queries didn't compile into the same thing. Black magic.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the explain plans; can you please post them? Also, which Oracle version?

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty interesting. For SQL Server it is purely semantic.

Comment: @Aleksej I'm afraid I can't, I'd be in violation of the security policy at work. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Are there any profiles, outlines, or SQL Plan Baselines in the "Notes" section of the explain plan?  Changing the text of the query may prevent those things from working.

Answer (score 1):

could be that the WHERE c.id = e.car_id   addition is a way for control the order in which the tables are used to perform the proper search  .. 
this could a way for  forcing  the query optimizer  to use as main table the table in where condition and the table related  beacause the  the sequence of table joins could not so valid for searching as is usefull for understand the query logic

Comment: I think this is what's happening. Adding the check to the where clause changes the join order in execution plan. I'm going to experiment with the ORDERED hint and see if I can get the same behaviour without the repeated condition.

Comment: @RobertBain   . try  and let me  know   ... if you mean the sequence  in which the join are writtens  this remember me  the way the query optimizer  was influenced  when there is not explicit join sintax and the all  the tables was written side by side  comma separated .. then the most right was name the lead table because was evaluetedc first in table scan .. could be also the with explicit join a new query optimizer  this concept is lost and then the where addiction force this behavior  .. hope di comment is useful ..

Comment: scaisEdge, see the update above. I don't have a conclusive answer.

Comment: I think is like i suggested  at the end of my previous comment .. the sequence of join don't  allow at the  query optimizer to find the lead table  (   the better starting scan for query) .. and the on condtion in join don't add info at the query optimizer ... instead addig a where  condition  introduce an new element for query optimizer evaluation .. that force the scan  staring qwith this ..